# Polar ‎decomposition ‎of ‎$ ‎T‎$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

‎let ‎‎$‎T ‎\in‎ B ( H )‎$ ‎and‎  ‎‎$ T ‎=U ‎\mid T ‎\mid‎$ ‎‎is‎ Polar ‎decomposition ‎of ‎‎$ ‎T‎$‎.‎‎

> How can be proved the following conditions?

a: ‎if ‎$ ‎T‎^{*} ‎T‎$‎ ‎is ‎invertible, ‎then  ‎$ ‎U‎ $ ‎‎is  a ‎isometric ‎and ‎$ U‎=  T‎ (‎ ‎‎ T‎^{*} T ) ‎‎^{1/2}‎‎‎‎$‎‎.‎‎

b:‎ ‎if ‎$ ‎T‎^{*} ‎T‎$‎ ‎is ‎invertible, ‎then  ‎$ ‎U‎ $ ‎is  a ‎unitary ‎operator.‎

c: ‎if‎ ‎‎$‎T ‎\in‎ B ( H )‎$,‎then ‎for ‎all‎  ‎‎$ x‎ ‎\in H ‎‎‎‎$‎,‎ ‎$  ‎\parallel‎ ‎\mid T‎ ‎‎\mid x‎ ‎‎\parallel =‎ ‎‎\parallel T‎ x‎ ‎‎\parallel‎‎ $‎.

thank for your attention.

Comment: In (a), you probably mean $(T^*T)^{-1/2}$ instead of $+1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $T^*T$ is invertible, its inverse it positive and so it makes sense to get $(T^*T)^{-1/2}$, so $|T|$ is also invertible. Since $T=U|T|$, by multiplying on the right by $|T|^{-1}$ we get 
$$
U=T\,|T|^{-1}=T(T^*T)^{-1/2}.
$$
Now
$$
U^*U=(T^*T)^{-1/2}T^*T(T^*T)^{-1/2}=I,
$$
so $U$ is an isometry. A similar computation shows that $UU^*=I$, so $U$ is a unitary.

The last equality is a straightforward computation:
$$
\|\,|T|x\|^2=\langle |T|x,|T|x\rangle=\langle |T|^2x,x\rangle=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\|Tx\|^2. 
$$